# SQL/DUNE ANALYTICS query for all erc-20 holders on specific date

Tags: sql, ethereum, cryptocurrency, chainlink, dune

I was wondering if there was a way to query all addresses holding an erc-20 token on a specific date i.e. wallet address of all wallets holding $LINK on May 1st, 2019. If I'm correct using "evt_transfer" is only showing wallets that bought or sold $LINK on that day which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Note that questions on Stack Overflow *must* be about programming. If your question doesn't involve programming, you could try our sister site [ethereum.se] instead.